# Laravel Validator - Get error messages as an array in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Here is my laravel validation

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'template_id' => 'required',
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:user,email'],
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
        ]);
```

If i print `$validation->messages()` i am getting below

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object
(
    [messages:protected] => Array
        (
            [template_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The template id field is required.
                )

            [first_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The first name field is required.
                )

        )

    [format:protected] => :message
)
```

But I want like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => The template id field is required.
    [1] => The first name field is required.
)
```

There is the specific use of that so needs this
**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'template_id' => 'required',
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:user,email'],
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
        ]);
```

**if you want all errors same time you just write code like**

```
$validation->messages()->all()
```

**or if you want one by one error so write code like**

```
$validation->messages()->first()
```

Comment: please accept this answe  and give upvote this answer thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could try asking the `MessageBag` for all the messages:

```
$validation->messages()->all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getMessageBag` method present in validator class.

```
 $validation->getMessageBag()->first();
```

Also you can set custom error messages like below:

```
if(User::where('email', $email)->first())
{
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('password', 'Please enter correct Password');
}
else
{
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('email', 'Email does not exists');
}
```